# How to fix bidi problems in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, hebrew

I'm currently having issues with Microsoft Word being slightly too helpful. I have a few documents in Hebrew that were written in Word 2007, that when viewed in later versions come out completely backwards.

Meaning that the text `שלום עליכם` is coming out `עליכם שלום`.

I assume that this is because in newer versions Word is adding in RTL-overrides and other unicode formatting things. Is there any way to turn off this functionality, or otherwise view my files in the correct order?

EDIT: selecting everything and setting the direction to RTL seems to help somewhat, but leaves me with a similar issue. Word automatically flips parentheses and other punctuation. This is undesirable for situations like Rabbinic Hebrew, where  apostrophes denote a single numeral, i.e. `שחיטה ד' ב'`. (The irony here is that Stack Exchange is also doing the same issue) If there is a solution to this short of switching software it would be amazing. Parentheses are also a killer, where `(כמו זה)` appears as `)כמו זה(`

Comment: You might try LibreOffice to view the docs. A fix to make them viewable in  MS Word is to convert them to graphics, e.g. via screenshots or print to PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a semi-solution. If you cut the whole document and then paste it as text, then it shows up correctly. I now have a sneaking suspicion that the issue is font related, so more testing is needed.

EDIT: an actual solution is to select the whole document and run the visual basic command selection.rtlrun. I find it frustrating that you can't find such a straightforward thing on the internet....